# How to setup a virtual host on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Implemented the following steps. But it is not working.

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/new site
```

- Added `ServerName` and Document root in new host file
- Enable the site `sudo a2ensite sitename`
- Added line `127.0.0.1 new hot name` in `/etc/host` file
- Added the following line in the `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` file

  ```
  # Include the virtual host configurations:
  Include sites-enabled/hostfilename
  ```

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask. Are those the exact commands you used? (Do they include those spaces in them?)

Comment: there is no space. These are example only

Comment: Please provide the exact commands that you used. If you don't want to divulge personal information, replace those parts by something innocuous.

Comment: sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/zfapp,

sudo a2ensite zfapp,

127.0.0.1 zfapp in /etc/host file

Comment: You shouldn't add the `Include sites-enabled/zfapp` entry in `apache2.conf`. You shouldn't have to do any modification in `apache2.conf` whatsoever.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu installation your local machine? is it a remote server? is it a virtual machine? Basically, are you accessing apache from a different OS installation?

Comment: Removed modification from apache2.conf. This is local machine and Apache is intalled in my machine

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://github.com/Aslamkv/vh :)

This tool lets you add and remove virtualhost in Ubuntu by doing every configuration for you. It is simple and easy to use.

#### Installation

1. Download the files listed at the link GitHub webpage into any folder and open that folder in terminal
2. Type in terminal `./install.sh`
3. Type in terminal `vh` to install a VirtualHost or `vhu` to uninstall a previously installed one

Disclaimer: I am the author :P

Answer (score 0):

create or copy virtualhost file and named example.com in /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com

add example.com to /etc/hosts

add minimal config for virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com    # sitename
DocumentRoot /path/to/site
</VirtualHost>

sudo a2ensite example.com

sudo service apache2 restart

curl -I http://example.com
```

Comment: Do you mean to remove other configurations from host file

Comment: Did. It is not working. Server not found

Comment: This is example. Simple add any hostname in /etc/hosts. Sorry my bad english

Comment: Show your file /etc/hosts and /etc/apache2/sites-available/hostname

Comment: Hostname file <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName zfapp.lcl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/zf/zendapp/public/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: /etc/host file - 127.0.0.1       zfapp.lcl

Comment: Where is index.php file? /var/www/zf/zendapp/public/  or /var/www/zf/zendapp or /var/www/zf  ???

Comment: check permissions 
chown -R www-data:www:data /var/www (or your user on whose behalf the running apache)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32160/discussion-between-manashb-and-pavel-popov).

Comment: Added index.php file. Checked permission user or me is owner and www-data is group owner
But it is not working

Comment: which directory the index.php file? Probably an invalid path?

Comment: Path for index.php file -  /var/www/zf/zendapp/public/